# ipv6 multicast address shows scope 2(link local) while ping google dns. Should it not be e(global)?

Tags: ipv6

I have a doubt about ipv6 multicast address. When i ping google dns (2001:4860:4860::8888) with ipv6 the solicited node multicast address shown in tcpdump is ff02::1:ff13:7e5 here scope has value 2 which means link-local.

should it not be e meaning global scope?

Comment: Why would it be global? The solicited node, like ARP for IPv4, is only on the local link.

Comment: maybe i am confused. In this ping operation are the packets not leaving internal network to external network.how can this be local link?.I read somewhere that the local-link are not externally routable .and in which scenario will thw node multicast address has scope as e

Comment: Traffic destined for a different network is delivered to the gateway on your local network. In IPv4, your host would use ARP to get the layer-2 address of its configured router. IPv6 uses the solicited node address for the same thing. ARP sends broadcasts, which IPv6 does not have. Broadcasts interrupt every host on the LAN, but the solicited node address probably only interrupts one host, so the IPv6 way is less burdensome to the hosts on the LAN.

Comment: @Ron: you should put that in an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Traffic destined for a different network is delivered to the gateway on your local network. In IPv4, your host would use ARP to get the layer-2 address of its configured router. IPv6 uses ND with the solicited node address for the same thing. ARP sends broadcasts, which IPv6 does not have. Broadcasts interrupt every host on the LAN, but the solicited node address probably only interrupts one host, so the way IPv6 discovers the layer-2 address is less burdensome to the hosts on the LAN.

What you are seeing in the Link-local multicast to the solicited node address is the Neighbor Discovery of your configured gateway. Once your host has that, it uses the layer-2 address of the gateway to build the frames for the IPv6 packets to Google. The frames for the ping are then delivered to your router at layer-2, but are addressed to Google's Global IPv6 address at layer-3.